# C++ program.exe has stopped working on build & run using codeblocks but works with ideone

Tags: c++, codeblocks

This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

class Block{

private:
    int* costs;
    const static int sz=1000000000;
    void generate_dp_costs(){

        for(int i=0;i<sz;i++){
            int cut_cost = costs[int(i/2)] + costs[int(i/3)] + costs[int(i/4)];
            costs[i] = std::max(i, cut_cost);
        }
    }

public:
    Block(){
        costs = (int*)malloc((sz+1)*sizeof(int));
        generate_dp_costs();
    }

    int optimum_cost(int weight){
        return costs[weight];
    }
};

int main(){
    Block b;
    int weight,cost;
    std::cin>>weight;
    cost = b.optimum_cost(weight);
    std::cout<<cost<<std::endl;
}
```

It gives program.exe has stopped working on build and run using code::blocks but works fine on online compilers like ideone. What might be the problem here?

Comment: 1000000000 times `sizeof(int)` is quite a lot of memory - I'm not sure every operating system can give you that much continuous memory when calling `malloc`

Comment: Since your executable requires 4GB in RAM, do you have such amount of memory available, and are you compiling the code as 64-bit application?

Comment: Also `generate_dp_costs()` exhibits *undefined behavior* as you are accessing array elements that have not been initialized

Comment: I think the size was the problem. Changing it to 1000 didn't cause any error. I have 8 gb ram and I am not sure if I was compiling the code as a 64 bit application

Comment: by the way, as this is C++ you should prefer `std::vector` over your raw array. e.g.: `std::vector<int> costs(sz+1, 0);` (also prefer using smart pointers over doing raw memory allocations and `malloc` is barely ever correct)

Comment: @Krash As UnholySheep explained, such allocation requires **continuous** 4GB memory block. If your memory is fragmented in a way, that such block is unavailable (even if you have more available memory in total) - such crash is possible.

Comment: @UnholySheep But for every index, generate_dp_costs only accesses elements that were previously assigned some value. But I think I should assign 0 to the 0-th index. Thanks, it was a mistake on my part.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius It all makes sense now.

Comment: On the very first iteration you are accessing the element at index 0, which has not been initialized at that point

Comment: Since `i` is an `int`, so is `i/2`, etc. There's no point in casting the result to `int`.